# Typescript: hash of constructors

Tags: typescript

I have an abstract class that represents data models. Let's call it Model. It's actually parameterized in the ModelData type, which represents the kind of data that the model actually has. So:

```
export interface ModelData { type: string; attributes: {} }
export class Model<D extends ModelData> {}
export interface UserData extends ModelData 
  { type: 'users', attributes: { name: string; }}
export class Users extends Model<UserData> {}
```

the problem is that I'd like to keep a repository of model constructors. When my data store sends me a list of references shaped like: `{ type: 'users', id: 1 }` I like to be able to do `refs.map(v => new ctors[v.type]({id: v.id}))` or something like that.

The problem is that I don't know how to declare that "this object contains a string indexed set of subclass constructors.

I used to do

```
private types: { [type: string]: typeof Model }
```

and then

```
find<T extends ModelData>(ref: ModelReference): Model<T> {
  return new types[ref.type]({id: ref.id})
}
```

more or less (extra null guards and other code omitted for brevity.

This isn't actually correct - what I'm actually returning is something that `extends Model<T>`, and what I'm storing in types is not `typeof Model`, but `extends typeof Model`.

Prior to 2.4.1 (I assume this has to do with implicit generic changes) the code compiled without complaining, despite not being correct. I'm happy with *making* it correct, but I'm not sure how I can actually express this using typescript.

The specific thing I've got is a set of `ModelData` types, which define different shapes to the attributes and relationships properties of the ModelData, and a set of classes that extend Model for each of those ModelData types. So while technically I could return a Model, I'd rather return a User, because I may put some extra convenience methods on User.

So, is it possible to say, "this thing contains a string-indexed group of constructors, and all those constructors follow the pattern "extends AbstractClass"?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest doing something like:

```
const types = {
  'users': Users,
  // ... other Models
}

function find<K extends keyof typeof types>(ref: { type: K }): typeof types[K]['prototype'] {
  return new types[ref.type](); // this only works if all Models have no-arg constructors
}
```

If you need to verify that `types` is of the right thing, there is a way to refer to a constructor of something using the `new` keyword:

```
type Constructor<T> = {
  new(...args: any[]): T;
  readonly prototype: T;
}
```

If I wanted to say "this object has values which are constructors for an appropriate `Model` type where the key is the same as the `ModelData['type']` value", I'd say:

```
type ModelMap<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: Constructor<Model<ModelData & { type: K }>>
}
function verifyTypes<T>(types: T, alsoTypes: ModelMap<T>) { }
verifyTypes(types, types);
```

If `verifyTypes()` gives you a compiler error, it's because one of the values is bad:

```
const types = {
   'user': Users
}
verifyTypes(types, types); // error: type of property 'user' is incompatible
```

Note that the compiler will only get angry if your `Model` types actually hold onto some property of the right `ModelData` type.  If they are empty as your example shows, all your types will be structurally identical and the compiler will never complain:

```
export class Model<D extends ModelData> { 
  data: D; // that's enough 
}
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: hmm, this gets a lot closer to what I need. Is there any way to use types as an instance variable there, so I could do `find<K extends keyof typeof this.types>`? (that didn't work out of the box). This lets me actually define the real types in a subclass of my datastore (the datastore is generic, the subclass adds the concrete, project-specific datatypes)

Comment: You could try `this['types']` instead of `typeof this.types`, but I think `this` polymorphism may trip this up.  If your class name is `DataStore` and it has a `types` property, then you can use `DataStore['types']` instead of `typeof this.types`.